# How to pass class_name Option to Generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generate, rails-generators

I am using Rails' generators to produce things like models in my app.

My models are commonly using the `class_name` option on relations.

Is it possible to generate a model from the command line and pass the value for `class_name`?  I specifically want to avoid modifying the model after the generator runs.

An example of what I hope exists is something like:

```
rails generate model Book title:string author:belongs_to{class_name:User}
```

Then the generated `Book` model would look like:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't pass `class_name` as an option to the `generator`. It is **not a valid option** to the generator command. You can see the list of available options by running

```
rails g model --help
```

I believe the only way is to manually edit the models to specify the `class_name`